# Как реализован счётчик лайков ВКонтакте?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вконтакте

При нажатии на лайк ВКонтакте число, отображающее количество уже поставленных лайков, медленно прокручивается на 1 (или больше) вперёд. То есть, если уже есть 555 лайков, то последняя цифра будет двигаться вниз, а на её место сверху придёт шестёрка.

При этом в коде число 555 не разбивается на цифры, вставленные в `div`'ы или `span`'ы, а отображается в блоке `post_like_counter` целиком.

Каким образом это реализовано?

Comment: Пример нужен. А по описанию сложно сказать, разве что вероятно на `margin` закручено.

Comment: Скорее всего, оно разбивается, просто впоследствие лишние элементы удаляются.

Comment: возможно число разбивается при клике, а потом возвращается в прежний блок, или же вычисляется новое значение счетчика, и вычисляется число изсменяемых символов, вставляется в бло, который наплывает на текущий, в конце анимации блок удаляется а в post_like_counter просто отображается число.

Comment: По-моему тебе нужно ajax.

Comment: `При этом в коде число 555 не разбивается на цифры, вставленные в div'ы или span'ы, а отображается в блоке post_like_counter целиком.`

Откуда такая уверенность? Мне просто лень искать те строки, которые все это делают, но если вы нашли — скажите, где именно?

А вообще, они вставляют внутрь этого спана див, в котором все и происходит. Так что кажется, число все-таки разбивается на составляющие.

Comment: Ещё как разбивается. [Вот как выглядит разметка посреди анимации 13 -> 14](http://i.imgur.com/Scb7QtH.png). Можете проверить сами, повесив в Хроме на контейнер с числом "Break on > Subtree modifications". Заодно и связанный код увидите.

Comment: @D-side опубликуйте Ваш комментарий в виде ответа

Answer (score 5):

У вас вопрос построен на неверном предположении, что число не разбивается на цифры.

#### А оно разбивается.

Взгляните на DOM в момент перехода. Вот скриншот из Chrome Dev Tools посреди перехода из 13 в 14.

[image: Скриншот]

- `counter_const` для цифры `1`, которая осталась неподвижной.
- классы `counter_anim_*` для цифр `3` и `4`, участвующих в анимации.

#### Как убедиться?

Chrome Dev Tools это штука довольно продвинутая.

Найдя элемент DOM, в котором должны произойти изменения, можно щёлкнуть на нём правой кнопкой мыши и установить на нём "Break on" > "Subtree modifications". Тогда любые изменения в этом поддереве приведут к останову всех процессов на странице и запуску JS-отладчика (хотя в данном случае это вторично).